# How to read runtime log file and create a alert

Tags: javascript, java, amazon-web-services, spring-mvc, amazon-ec2

We have one requirement where if we get the Out of Memory from JVM then we have to create the Alert. now my issue is Out of Memory error we can get from any java class and my requirement is when we get Out of Memory in console logs i have to create the alert.
is there any way to read the run time logs and found specific error and create a alert.

Basically In my project I want to put global try catch for Out of Memory check.

Comment: do the alert need to be fired from inside the JVM application? An OFM exception indicates that the application is not running as expected any more - so the altering system should be outside the ecosystem of the JVM. You can use for example the ELK-Stack from Elastic: https://www.elastic.co/what-is/elk-stack

Comment: No for the alert i have to use Cloudwatch Metrics so when i will get the error in logs i have to put that on Cloudwatch Metrics.

Comment: than you should add this context information to the question. I can not help you with Cloudwatch

Comment: Alert work i can do that, my doubt is how i can catch the Out of Memory in java class as it can be throw from any class in the project i can't update each class with Out of Memory check.